# Spring 3 AOP and Mongo DB Integration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-aop

I was using Mongo DB with Spring Data, everything was working fine until I decided to use Spring AOP Aspects for the logging purpose. Here is my spring configuration, Person Service and LoggingAspect Code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">




    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vaap" />

    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="rakeshdb" mongo-ref="mongo"/>



    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="personService" class="com.vaap.PersonService"></bean>


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy  proxy-target-class="true"/>

   <bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.vaap.aop.LoggingAspect" />



</beans>


package com.vaap;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery;

public class PersonService implements IPersonService {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "person";

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(Person.class)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(Person.class);
        }
        person.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        // mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, collectionName);

        // DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonStr);

        mongoTemplate.insert(person, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public List<Person> listPerson() {

        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Person.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public String getPersonJSON() {
        BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery("{'status':'Active'}");

        return mongoTemplate.find(basicQuery, String.class, COLLECTION_NAME)
                .toString();
    }

    public void deletePerson(Person person) {
        mongoTemplate.remove(person, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public void updatePerson(Person person) {
        mongoTemplate.insert(person, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }
}

package com.vaap.aop;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Configurable
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);



    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))", throwing = "e")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
        log.error("An exception has been thrown in "
                + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()");
        log.error("Cause :" + e.getCause());
    }

    @Around("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("The method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
                + "() begins with " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
            log.info("The method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
                    + "() ends with " + result);
            return result;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("Illegal argument "
                    + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()) + " in "
                    + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()");
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

If I comment `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy  proxy-target-class="true"/>` line everything works fine otherwise I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDbFactory' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory': Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory]: 
Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments
```

I know, it may not be spring problem as this is standard CGI Lib behaviour but what alternatives do I have if I want to go with XML configuration and want to use both, spring data with mongodb and spring aop for logging.

Comment: Your aspect is basically forcing everything to be proxied, including infrastructure classes, not sure if that is what you want. You might want to extend your pointcut to exclude spring classes or to only proxy/match your own classes.

Comment: My bad! Idea was to proxy my own classes. Got it working now. Thanks a ton Deinum!

Comment: I'm still struggling with this.  I'm using Spring Mongo Repository Interfaces, and I've locked my pointcut directly at one of the interfaces, but I get errors the CGLIB is not able to generate a proxy for and instance of com.sun.proxy.$ProxyNN.  That makes sense, Spring Mongo repository is implementing my interfaces with dynamic proxy...  Has anyone found a way to get AOP to work with interface repositories?